# How do you calculate the expected value of $e^{-X}$?

Tags: expected-value

If $X$ is a random variable, I would like to be able to calculate something like $$E(e^{-X})$$

How can I do this? Thank you so much.

Comment: this is the moment generating function $m_{X}(t)=E[\exp(tX)]$ evaluated at $t=-1$.

Comment: A specific example:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/175196/expectation-of-e-x-when-x-is-log-normal/176162#176162

Answer (score 15, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, your specific question can be solved by evaluating the [moment generating function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moment-generating_function) and $t=-1$, but it appears you may be asking the more general question of how to calculate the expected value of a function of a random variable.

In general, if $X$ has density function $p$, then

$$ E \left( f(X) \right) = \int_{D} f(x) p(x) dx $$

where $D$ denotes the support of the random variable. For discrete random variables, the corresponding expectation is

$$ E \left( f(X) \right) = \sum_{x \in D} f(x) P(X=x) $$

These identities follow from the [definition of expected value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#General_definition). In your example $f(X) = \exp(-X)$, so you would just plug that into the definition above.

**Continuous example:** Suppose $X \sim N(0,1)$, then

\begin{align*}
E \left (\exp(-X) \right) &= \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-x} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-x^2/2} dx \\
&=  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-(x^2 + 2x)/2} dx \\
&=  \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-(x^2 + 2x + 1)/2} e^{1/2} dx \\
&=  e^{1/2} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \underbrace{\frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi}} e^{-(x+1)^2/2}}_{{\rm density \ of \ a \ N(-1,1)}} dx \\
&= e^{1/2} 
\end{align*}

**Discrete example:** $X \sim {\rm Bernoulli}(p)$. Then

\begin{align*}
E \left( \exp(-X) \right) &= \sum_{i=0}^{1} e^{-i} P(X=i) \\ 
&= (1-p)e^0 + pe^{-1} \\ 
&= (1-p) + p/e 
\end{align*}

Comment: $Y = f(X)$ is a random variable which we assume for simplicity is a continuous random variable with density function $g_Y(y)$. Thus the _definition_ of $E[Y]$ is $$E[Y] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}yg_Y(y)\,\mathrm dy,$$ and so the question is _why_ is the expectation of $Y$ **also** given by $$E[Y] = E[f(X)] = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x) g_X(x)\,\mathrm dx?$$ That the two competing formulas for $E[Y]$ both give the same value is worth mentioning somewhere, possibly linking to a proof of this remarkable result which the Wikipedia link calls the Law of the Unconscious Statistician.

Comment: @DilipSarwate, doesn't this just follow from the change of variable theorem?

Comment: Measure theoreticaly, you prove it when $f$ is an indicator, then when $f$ is a nonnegative simple function, then when $f$ is a nonnegative measurable function (using monotone convergence), and finally when $f$ is an arbitrary measurable function.