# expectation of $e^{-x}$ when x is log-normal

Tags: probability, expected-value, lognormal-distribution, hazard, moment-generating-function

I'm trying to find the expected value of $ e^{-x} $ when $ x$ is log-normal. I know that if $ x \sim N(\mu, \sigma) $ then $ E[e^x] = e^{\mu + \frac{1}{2}\sigma^2} $, the expectation of a log-normal.

I'm trying to find the expectation of the exponent of the negative of a log-normal: $ E[e^{-e^x}] $ where $ x\sim N(\mu, \sigma) $.

Comment: Your title and question are confusing! X is normal  or X is log normal? This $x\sim N(\mu, \sigma)$  only suggested $X$ is normal

Comment: I don't see the confusion. The title asks about the expectation of $ e^{-x} $ when x is log-normal. I was just clarifying that i already know the answer to the expectation of a log-normal RV. I was also trying to clarify by asking for $ E[e^{-e^x}] $ which is equivalent to $ e^{-y} $ when y is log-normal.

Comment: This appears to require numerical or approximate methods.

Comment: Because x is log-normal, i've tried using the MGF but it has yielded no results. I can do numerical approximations but was hoping this was an easy answer that I just couldn't find. My question relates to the probability of survival for an exponential hazard function when $ \lambda $ is drawn from a log-normal distribution.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Suppose $X$ is log-normal random variable. The question is about the expectation 
$\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{E} \E \exp(-X)$. This is related to the moment-generating function of $X$,
$$
  M_X(t) = \E e^{tX}
$$
So you are asking for $M_X(-1)$, which do exist, but no closed expression is known. So, you could try numerical integration (example in R):

```
> f  <-  function(x) exp(-x)*dlnorm(x)
> integrate(f,0,+Inf)
0.3817565 with absolute error < 1.8e-05
> # Or by stochastic simulation:
> mean(exp(-rlnorm(100E6,0,1)))
[1] 0.3818151
```

If you want some analytic approximations, have a look at:  Søren Asmussen, Jens Ledet Jensen, Leonardo Rojas-Nandayapa: "On the Laplace transform of the lognormal distribution."